# How to draw a block scheme for SEM (Structural equation modeling ) in R?

Tags: r, visualization

In this question I will use `lavaan` tutorial examples.
They provide the following SEM model:

```
model <- '
  # measurement model
    ind60 =~ x1 + x2 + x3
    dem60 =~ y1 + y2 + y3 + y4
    dem65 =~ y5 + y6 + y7 + y8
  # regressions
    dem60 ~ ind60
    dem65 ~ ind60 + dem60
  # residual correlations
    y1 ~~ y5
    y2 ~~ y4 + y6
    y3 ~~ y7
    y4 ~~ y8
    y6 ~~ y8
'
```

And they also have a nice block scheme for this model:

[image]

My question is:

**Are there any libraries for drawing such diagrams in R?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `lavaanPlot` package,
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lavaanPlot/vignettes/Intro_to_lavaanPlot.html

Here's a tutorial,
https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/seminars/rsem/